# Array-List not contains

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a LIST with two ATTRIBUTs/OBJECTs. The first IS AN INT-ARRAY for two IDs.

I want to add a new OBJECT into the LIST, only if the Value **12 *and* 21** (only in combination) will NOT exist in the Ids-Array of the hole LIST.
//if just one single ID will be found everything is okay - only the combination of both IDs needs to jump into the ELSE-Case. :)

*12 and 21 will be vars later, so no static values

I don't know why, but this isn't working...

if (Id != Destination.Id && **!(ThisDistances.Exists(x => x.Ids.Contains(12)) && ThisDistances.Exists(x => x.Ids.Contains(21)))**)
{ ... }

```
public class DistanceData
{
    public int[] Ids;
    public int Distance;
}

protected void MakeDistances(int Id, double GeoLat, double GeoLon, int Limit = 100)
{
    int i = 0;
    List<DistanceData> ThisDistances = new List<DistanceData>();
    foreach (var Destination in Destinations)
    {
        if (Id != Destination.Id && !(ThisDistances.Exists(x => x.Ids.Contains(12)) && ThisDistances.Exists(x => x.Ids.Contains(21))))
        {
            ThisDistances.Add(new DistanceData()
            {
                Ids = new int[2] { Id, Destination.Id },
                Distance = (int)Math.Round(6378388 * Math.Acos(Math.Sin(GeoLat) * Math.Sin(Destination.GeoLat) + Math.Cos(GeoLat) * Math.Cos(Destination.GeoLat) * Math.Cos(Destination.GeoLon - GeoLon)), 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
            });
            if (++i > 10) break;
        }
    }
    ThisDistances = ThisDistances.OrderBy(x => x.Distance).Take(Limit).ToList();
    foreach (var ThisDistance in ThisDistances)
    {
        Response.Write("<i><b>" + ThisDistance.Distance + "</b> (" + ThisDistance.Ids[0] + "," + ThisDistance.Ids[1] + ")</i><br />");
    }
}
```

How can I check, that **both** IDs are NOT in the IDs-Array of the ObjectList?

Comment: Research boolean algebra: `!(exists(a) && exists(b))` is `!exists(a) || !exists(b)`. You want `!exists(a) && !exists(b)`, which is `!(exists(a) || exists(b))`.

Comment: You could also use the `false` instead of the exclamation point, which some people find more expressive.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe in 2 words : De-morgan.

Comment: Indeed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
foreach (var Destination in Destinations)
{
    if (Id != Destination.Id && (ThisDistances.Exists(x => x.Ids.Contains(12) && x.Ids.Contains(21)) == false))
    {
        ThisDistances.Add(new DistanceData()
        {
            Ids = new int[2] { Id, Destination.Id },
            Distance = (int)Math.Round(6378388 * Math.Acos(Math.Sin(GeoLat) * Math.Sin(Destination.GeoLat) + Math.Cos(GeoLat) * Math.Cos(Destination.GeoLat) * Math.Cos(Destination.GeoLon - GeoLon)), 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
        });
        if (++i > 10) break;
    }
}
```